# WordPress javascript variable scope

Tags: javascript, wordpress, d3.js, global-variables

I have managed to use WordPress Custom Fields to create a bunch of fields in a template, when it's in edit mode. I have worked out how to access the values, using JavaScript and I have updated the PHP for this template with a JavaScript section to create global variables from the form data. In this style:
`var project_name = '<?php the_field('project_name'); ?>';`
I've tried without success to put the php calls directly into the d3 script.

I also have the wp-d3 plugin. I have put a test script in, which works in situ but I can't see how I should exploit the global variables to drive the d3.js. In this test case, I'm just trying to set the colour of three circles, using a value stored in the global variables.

It's possibly significant that the SVG is inserted before my script section, containing the variable declaration?

This is the php script

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Project Status
*/
if ( apply_filters( 'czr_four_do', false ) ) {
  do_action( 'czr_four_template' );
  return;
}
?>
<?php do_action( '__before_main_wrapper' ); ##hook of the header with get_header ?>
<div id="main-wrapper" class="<?php echo implode(' ', apply_filters( 'tc_main_wrapper_classes' , array('container') ) ) ?>">

    <?php do_action( '__before_main_container' ); ##hook of the featured page (priority 10) and breadcrumb (priority 20)...and whatever you need! ?>

    <div class="container" role="main">
        <div class="<?php echo implode(' ', apply_filters( 'tc_column_content_wrapper_classes' , array('row' ,'column-content-wrapper') ) ) ?>">

            <?php do_action( '__before_article_container' ); ##hook of left sidebar?>

                <div id="content" class="<?php echo implode(' ', apply_filters( 'tc_article_container_class' , array( CZR_utils::czr_fn_get_layout(  CZR_utils::czr_fn_id() , 'class' ) , 'article-container' ) ) ) ?>">

                    <?php do_action( '__before_loop' );##hooks the header of the list of post : archive, search... ?>

                        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : ##all other cases for single and lists: post, custom post type, page, archives, search, 404 ?>

                                <?php the_post(); ?>

                                <?php do_action( '__before_article' ) ?>

                                    <article <?php czr_fn__f( '__article_selectors' ) ?>>
                                        <?php do_action( '__loop' ); ?>
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                                var project_colour = '<?php the_field('project_colour'); ?>';
                                                var project_name = '<?php the_field('project_name'); ?>';
                                                var project_type = '<?php the_field('project_type'); ?>';
                                                var executive_owner = '<?php the_field('executive_owner'); ?>';
                                                var director = '<?php the_field('director'); ?>';
                                                var key_wins = '<?php the_field('key_wins'); ?>';
                                                var initiatives = '<?php the_field('initiatives'); ?>';
                                                var whats_new = '<?php the_field('whats_new'); ?>';
                                                var red_flags = '<?php the_field('red_flags'); ?>';
                                                var design_thinking_score = '<?php the_field('design_thinking_score'); ?>';
                                        </script>
                                    </article>
                                <?php do_action( '__after_article' ) ?>

                            <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php endif; ##end if have posts ?>

                    <?php do_action( '__after_loop' );##hook of the comments and the posts navigation with priorities 10 and 20 ?>

                </div><!--.article-container -->

           <?php do_action( '__after_article_container' ); ##hook of left sidebar ?>

        </div><!--.row -->
    </div><!-- .container role: main -->

    <?php do_action( '__after_main_container' ); ?>

</div><!-- //#main-wrapper -->

<?php do_action( '__after_main_wrapper' );##hook of the footer with get_get_footer ?>
```

This is the wp-d3 code

```
var jsonCircles = [
  { "x-axis": 130, "y_axis": 50, "radius": 20, "color" : "green" },
  { "x_axis": 170, "y_axis": 170, "radius": 30, "color" : "purple"},
  { "x_axis": 310, "y_axis": 310, "radius": 50, "color" : "red"}];

var svgContainer = d3.select(".wpd3-1494-0").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 600)
                                    .attr("height", 400);

var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
                          .data(jsonCircles)
                          .enter()
                          .append("circle");

var circleAttributes = circles
                       .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
                       .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
                       .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
                       .style("fill", project_colour);
```

Note that on the last line, I've tried to capture the global variable containing a colour value  but this doesn't work. Using dev tools, I can see the generated code looks like this

```
<div class="wpd3-1494-0"><script type="text/javascript">function wpd3_1494_0 () {var jsonCircles = [
  { "x-axis": 130, "y_axis": 50, "radius": 20, "color" : "green" },
  { "x_axis": 170, "y_axis": 170, "radius": 30, "color" : "purple"},
  { "x_axis": 310, "y_axis": 310, "radius": 50, "color" : "red"}];
var svgContainer = d3.select(".wpd3-1494-0").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 600)
                                    .attr("height", 400);
var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
                          .data(jsonCircles)
                          .enter()
                          .append("circle");
var circleAttributes = circles
                       .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
                       .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
                       .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
                       .style("fill", project_colour);}; wpd3_1494_0();</script></div><p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>

                            <script type="text/javascript">
                        var project_colour = '#9ad66f';
                        etc...
```

And the error message is `ReferenceError: project_colour is not defined`

Comment: Based on the last code block where you show the generated code, it looks as though the D3 code is being output before your global colour variable. Can you change the order of one or both to get the colour variable output earlier?

Comment: I can't see how. If I wasn't in Wordpress, it'd be trivial but in Wordpress I'm stumped.

Comment: I did try moving the script var declaration section to in-between: 
`<?php do_action( '__before_article' ) ?>
....<in here>...
<article <?php czr_fn__f( '__article_selectors' ) ?>>`

but that didn't work

Comment: Which action hook is being used to render the D3 code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that term but I'd guess that it is being handled by the wp-d3 Chart Manager plugin. I've not explicitly coded anything to render the d3 code - My presumption is that the plugin manages the d3 library access and inserts the d3 at the appropriate point

Comment: I think I found the issue. I moved the var declaration section into <?php do_action( '__before_article' ) ?>, as before but I realised that I had some WYSIWYG fields later on which peppered the response with HTML tags and this seems to have had a knock on effect. I've switched to text area fields and later I'll tackle how to parse the multiline responses into an array so I can render each line as an entity in my infographic. Hopefully it's working now. Thanks all